# Filter a List<> content in to dictionary in Java

Tags: java, list, dictionary, collections

I have a List of a particular type of objects as follows:

```
List<Code>
```

The properties of Code class are as follows;

```
private Integer id;
private Amp amp;
private FF ff;
private Imp imp;
private Board b;
private Line line;
private int interface;
private String interfaceType;
private boolean chained;
```

I want to filter this list based on the interface. Interface can vary from 0-7, hence I want to create a dictionary as

```
Dictionary<int, List<Code>>
```

How do I filter the list according to the interface to create the dictionary?

Thanks in advance for an answer.

Comment: you should provide your custom `Comparator` to the `sort` method

Comment: What have you tried? It's not very clear to me what you are asking, but perhaps showing some code that you have tried will clear things up.

Comment: Note that this won't compile since `interface` is a keyword, you use it as a variable name. Secondly, it won't compile since you don't use the `Integer` wrapper class in your `Dictionary` (you can't use primitive types as parameterization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
List<Code> codes = ...;
Map<Integer, List<Code>> grouped = new HashMap<>();
for (Code code : codes) {
    if (! grouped.containsKey(code.getInterface()) {
        grouped.put(code.getInterface(), new ArrayList<Code>());
    }
    grouped.get(code.getInterface()).add(code);
}
```

Comment: Raw `ArrayList`? Why?

Comment: @Zhuinden Because of typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use guava Multimaps utilities to express your mapping. And then you put the result into a dictionary.

```
import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableListMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimaps;

public class Code {

    public int getInterface() {...}
    ...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Code> codes = new ArrayList<Code>();
        ImmutableListMultimap<Integer, Code> listMultimap = Multimaps.index(codes, new Function<Code, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer apply(Code code) {
                return code.getInterface();
            }
        });

        Hashtable<Integer, List<Code>> dictionary = new Hashtable<Integer, List<Code>>(Multimaps.asMap(listMultimap));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
List<Code> codes = <your_init>;
Dictionary<Integer, List<Code>> dict = new Hashtable<>();

//initialize dictionary
for ( int i = 0; i < 8; ++i )
{
  dict.put( i, new ArrayList<Code>() );
}

//iterate list and fill dictionary
for (Code code : codes )
{
  List<Code> item = dict.get( code.interface );
  item.add( code );
  dict.put( code.interface, item );
}
```

Comment: What is this "dictionary" that it allows non-Object template parameters (int)?

Comment: Generic parameter mustn't be primitive. `int` -> `Integer`

Comment: Moreover, [`Dictionary`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html) is `abstract` and cannot be instantiated.

Comment: You do not have to extract and re-insert the list from the dictionary to add items to it. Also, will break if there should ever be an interface number greater then 7.

Comment: Thanks for comments, I edited my post.
As to @tobias_k comment, I assumed that interface won't be other than 0-7, as it is said in the first post.